# Vue - Remove baseUrl from home page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

I set baseUrl to "/app", but I need to remove it when I click on home page. So when I click on home page instead of `emample.com/app` I need to get `emample.com`.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
```

.env

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URL=/app
```

Comment: can you post your `vue.config.js` file

Comment: Why not creating a root for both returning the same view?